# Suppose a class acts as an actor in the use case model. How will you represent it in the class diagram?

Tags: uml, software-design, class-diagram, use-case-diagram

i am confused in whether how a use case and a class diagram are reated? what i mean to ask is if i have a use case diagram how can i convert it into the class diagram or vice versa.

and also the above question.

I.m.o. the actor should be the name of the class with its respective attributes. but i am still confused as in how to frame the correct and appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The actor in the use-case is external to the system. The classes are internal to the system. So in principle, you don't represent an actor in a class diagram:

- If you want to have a class that represents an actor within the system (e.g. a player class to manage the player's state whereas the player appears to be an actor), use an ordinary class.
- If you want to represent the user interface that transmits information from/to an actor, you'd represent a [`«Boundary»` class](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary). It corresponds to the association between an actor and a use-case.
- If really you want to show an actor class in a class diagram, and none of the previous techniques would appear to be better suited, then you could consider representing it in a class shape, with the [keyword `«actor»` above its name](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-actor.html).

Answer (score 0):

In UML, "use cases" captures requirements (problem) and "class diagram" captures implementation details(solution). Actors are roles who interact with the system you are implementing.

For instance, let's consider the following requirements for a drone delivery system:

DroneDelvry, Inc. is starting a drone delivery service. The company manages a fleet of drone aircraft.

- users can request a drone to pick up items for delivery.
- When a customer schedules a pickup, a backend system assigns a drone and sends the user an estimated delivery time.
- While the delivery is in progress, the customer can track the drone's location, with a continuously updated ETA(Expected Time of Arrival).

Some of the use cases for the "customer" are:

- manage customers accounts (register, update etc.)
- handle delivery(pickup, notifications, etc.)
- track delivery status
- manage deliveries history (for a customer)
  Here the "customer" is the Actor

Some of the classes can be defined based on these use cases:

- customer (captures "customer" related details like address, registration details etc.)
- deliveryPickup (delivery pickup request)
- deliveryActive (active deliveries)
- deliveryHistory (deliveries history)
- deliveryPackage (delivery Package details)
- deliveryNotify (notify delivery status to the customer)

In this case, the actor "customer" is used as a class name in the class diagram.

Also attributes and methods can be added to these classes. For example:

deliveryPickup

- pickup  //pickup request
- status  //pickup done or not

deliveryActive

- pickupDateTime
- status //delivered or not

Comment: Hmm, smells a lot like ChatGPT

Comment: @GeertBellekens mod flag ?

Comment: @4b0 I just did

Comment: I am new contributor. I wrote this answer by hand(not generated by chatGPT). I thought providing example will help the reader. Please suggest ways to improve this answer. I am new contributor.